# File History first backup never succeeds. Nothing happens

Tags: windows, backup, windows-10

I have an Windows box, which originally had Windows 7 installed and was later on upgraded to Windows 10.

On Windows 10 I added a 3TB hard disk for backups. I set up the new hard disc as backup target and started the first backup. This now is some days ago, but whenever I check the status I get following message: `File History is saving copies of your files for the first time`.

On the backup disc nothing happens. There is created a folder `M:\FileHistory\username\boxname\Data`, but there are no files in it.

There is just a link (for whatever reason not a button) below, to stop the backup. When I restart it, I get the same message but nothing happens.

Anybody any idea, what could be the reason or what to do?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution. Keep in mind, I use a german version of windows. Hence, the menu point names may not be accurately translated.

In the control center > system and security > file history > extended settings

There is a link to the event viewer related to backup events.

It had some messages telling it could not save a file in a given folder. Deleting the folder, and also the BACKUP-DRIVE:\FileHistory folder on the backup drive solved the issues.

Comment: The correct english version of the path would be: `Control Panel\System and Security\File History\Advanced Settings`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but noticed that it was trying to save a full OneDrive, so I removed all cloud drives from the File History save and it completed just fine.